# Run a certain link without clicking the actual link button

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a script that replaces the current cookie, then goes to a link in the website, and then replace the next cookie. All the cookies are stored in an array.
I have the following code so far:

```
var i;
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    var cookie = arr[i];
    //setting the new cookie that was fetched from the array:
    document.cookie = 'cookieName='+cookie+'; path=/';
    //Now I need to run the <a href> which links to a relative path
    //I am currently in www.mydomain.com/page1/subpage1
    //And the href is to /page1/subpage2.I want the script to run this link every iteration
}
```

I need to run the `/page/subpage2` link without actually clicking it using JS.

This link doesn't actually changes the current page, it's a link that runs some server side code but you actually stay in the same page `www.mydomain.com/page1/subpage1`, so you don't have to redirect back to `page1/subpage1`

It's a simple website, and the links do not have id on their element, it's a table with links that look something like that:

```
<table>
<!--more rows here-->
<tr>                        
<td>                        
<a class='table-row' href='/page1/subpage2'> Click </a>
</td>
</tr>
<!--more rows here-->
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use forEach to cycle inside the array. Associate the el to the cookie and change the array element. Then trigger the click on the a which has the desidered href.

```
// never define variables inside the loop when possible
var cookie;
arr.forEach(function (el, ind) {
    cookie = el;
    arr[ind] = 'document.cookie = \"cookieName='+cookie+'; path=/;"';
    document.querySelector('a[href="mypath"]').triggerHandler('click');
});
```

Comment: I think I didn't use the correct word (click), what I want is that the link will be pressed automatically without mouse click, but that the javascript code will run the link, so maybe the click was misused here?

Comment: yeah I think the explanation was not really clear. 
To be honest I didn't understand yet what you want to achieve. You want to execute some code related to an href click but without really clicking the link with js neither?

Comment: Yes, and I also have a mistake in the code, I edited it, I accidentally wrote the cookie to array instead of setting it.
and also added some more explaining, hope it will be more clear

Comment: in your HTML there is no code associated on click with the a element. 
Is it a function? what is this code that you want to execute?
Please think to change the // now I want to click the link, otherwise anyone will think that you want to trigger a click on a link...

Comment: Use the XMLHttpRequest object to send a get request to your server instead of clicking it. Did you get what I mean? I am having dinner now I will update it once at the computer, it's a pain in the ass editing by phone the code here :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create new `click` event and dispatch it like it is in the code below.

In this example we loop through all links with class `table-row`, listen to clicks in order to see if they work (double the link text onClick), and dispatch `click` for every link.

`preventDefault()` is used to prevent navigating upon each click.

ES6 syntax is used for more clear code.

```js
const links = document.getElementsByClassName('table-row');

const forEach = o => fn => Array.prototype.forEach.call(o, fn);

const arr = [];

forEach(links)((link, i) => {
  arr[i] = 'document.cookie = \"cookieName='+link.href+'; path=/;"';
  
  // listen to click just to be able to see it in action

  link.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // for testing purposes
    const t = document.createTextNode(e.target.textContent);
    e.target.appendChild(t);
  })
  
  // here you generate a click programmatically:

  const customClick = new MouseEvent('click', 
    { "view": window, "bubbles": true, "cancelable": true });
  link.dispatchEvent(customClick); // generate click
})
```

```html
<table>
<!--more rows here-->
<tr>                        
<td>                        
<a class='table-row' href='/relative/path1'> Click1 </a>
</td>
<td>                        
<a class='table-row' href='/relative/path2'> Click2 </a>
</td>
<td>                        
<a class='table-row' href='/relative/path3'> Click3 </a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>                        
<td>                        
<a class='table-row' href='/relative/path4'> Click4 </a>
</td>
<td>                        
<a class='table-row' href='/relative/path5'> Click5 </a>
</td>
<td>                        
<a class='table-row' href='/relative/path6'> Click6 </a>
</td>
</tr>
<!--more rows here-->
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry, when I said click I didn't mean that I click it with mouse, but that the javascript code will run the link each iteration automatically, not that I do it?

Comment: Well, my code does exactly that - clicks links programmatically, one by one on each iteration. Event is triggered on the last line of code.

Comment: I've added comments to my code so you can see what's going on.